# How to fix wobble in outdoor pavers

Tags: deck, pavers

I have an outdoor area covered in pavers. The pavers are 2ft by 2ft. Under them is Brock PaverBase and under those is sand. The surface under the sand is as level as can be. There is some wobble in the pavers that is noticeable. I didn't use any polymeric joint sand due to the large size of the pavers. What can I do? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Seems like some surface debris like pebbles have worked between and ultimately under the pavers, making a fulcrum for wobble. See if you can't pull the paver out, find the irregularity, then put it back. Stone dust or polymeric sand isn't not necessary just because you have big pavers. Try adding some stone dust to see if it will interlock the pavers.

Comment: Okay. Originally, there was still wobble. This isn't a new problem, although due to the winter, the pavers move a lot more. They are porcelain so they also make an annoying squeak every time one moves. I can fix the irregularities, but do you think it might be easier to remove the PaverBase and simply lay the pavers straight on the sand? I don't know if PaverBase was designed for large pavers like I have. The area is quite large and a lot of pavers move.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't remove the paver base, which provides quite a bit of stability, but I'd consider a thin layer of sand over it to act as a buffer. If the base has joints or gaps that would allow the sand to drain, you could install a sheet of plastic or heavy landscape fabric first.